# How to change order of text to appear on arc - context 2d, and stop fill style overwriting on the canvas 2d (using with chart.js)?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, draw

So I trying to get build an arc with text on it as rounded rectangle in context 2d but the text is going under it and is getting hidden, also, the fill style for arc is getting overridden by the fill style for text. Here is what I am getting and what I want:

[image]

Here is the js fiddle with the code : https://jsfiddle.net/abhishek_soni/vzs6dLy9/19/

Here is the same code :

Html code :

```
<canvas></canvas>
```

Js code :

```
var roundRect = function(ctx, x, y, w, h, r) {
  var x2 = x + w;
  var y2 = y + h;

  if (w < 2 * r) r = w / 2;
  if (h < 2 * r) r = h / 2;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + r, y);
  ctx.arcTo(x2, y, x2, y2, r);
  ctx.arcTo(x2, y2, x, y2, r);
  ctx.arcTo(x, y2, x, y, r);
  ctx.arcTo(x, y, x2, y, r);
};

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.save();
roundRect(context, 0, 0, 50, 60, 20);
context.fillStyle = 'red'; // This should work, but it doesn't 
context.fill();
context.restore();

context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.fillText('Hey', 50, 80) // if I change this to 50 it hides behind the arc, which I don't want.
context.textAlign = "center";
context.fill();

context.save();
roundRect(context, 100, 100, 50, 90, 20);
context.fillStyle = 'red'; // This should work, but it doesn't 
context.fill();
context.restore();

context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.fillText('Hey', 90, 100) // if I change this to 50 it hides behind the arc, which I don't want.
context.textAlign = "center";
context.fill();

context.save();
roundRect(context, 300, 100, 50, 120, 20);
context.fillStyle = 'red'; // This should work, but it doesn't 
context.fill();
context.restore();

context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.fillText('Hey', 90, 130) // if I change this to 50 it hides behind the arc, which I don't want.
context.textAlign = "center";
context.fill();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are calling `fill()` after you create the text which you don't need. That `fill()` is being applied to the shape drawn previously. The purpose of methods like `fillText()` and `fillRect()` are to allow you to draw without the need to call `fill()` after.

Don't call fill after the text and it works.

Next to align your text in the center of the shape I would calculate the center and place the text there and then use `context.textAlign = 'center';` to center it.

Here's an example

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;

let center = {}
var roundRect = function(ctx, x, y, w, h, r) {
  var x2 = x + w;
  var y2 = y + h;
  center = {x: x + w/2, y: y + h/2}
  
  if (w < 2 * r) r = w / 2;
  if (h < 2 * r) r = h / 2;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + r, y);
  ctx.arcTo(x2, y, x2, y2, r);
  ctx.arcTo(x2, y2, x, y2, r);
  ctx.arcTo(x, y2, x, y, r);
  ctx.arcTo(x, y, x2, y, r);
  ctx.closePath();
};



context.fillStyle = 'red';
roundRect(context, 0, 0, 50, 60, 20);
context.fill();

context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.fillText('Hey', center.x, center.y);
context.textAlign = "center";

context.fillStyle = 'red';
roundRect(context, 100, 100, 50, 90, 20);
context.fill();

context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.fillText('Hey', center.x, center.y)
context.textAlign = "center";

context.fillStyle = 'red';
roundRect(context, 300, 100, 50, 120, 20);
context.fill();

context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.fillText('Hey', center.x, center.y);
context.textAlign = "center";
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

I'm also going to add an example using a class to do this. I prefer this over the other method. If you don't need different color shapes you can get rid of the color argument. And if you want different color text you can add one for that.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;

class roundRect {
  constructor(x, y, w, h, r, c) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.x2 = this.x + this.w;
    this.y2 = this.y + this.h;
    this.center = { x: x + w / 2, y: y + h / 2 };
    this.r = r;
    this.color = c;
  }
  drawShape() {
    if (this.w < 2 * this.r) this.r = this.w / 2;
    if (this.h < 2 * this.r) this.r = this.h / 2;
    
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.x + this.r, this.y);
    ctx.arcTo(this.x2, this.y, this.x2, this.y2, this.r);
    ctx.arcTo(this.x2, this.y2, this.x, this.y2, this.r);
    ctx.arcTo(this.x, this.y2, this.x, this.y, this.r);
    ctx.arcTo(this.x, this.y, this.x2, this.y, this.r);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }
  drawText() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.fillText("Hey", this.center.x, this.center.y); 
  }
}

let rect1 = new roundRect(0, 0, 50, 60, 20, 'red', 'Text')
let rect2 = new roundRect(60, 0, 50, 80, 20, 'lightblue', 'Text')
let rect3 = new roundRect(120, 0, 50, 100, 20, 'lightgreen', 'Text')

rect1.drawShape();
rect1.drawText();
rect2.drawShape();
rect2.drawText();
rect3.drawShape();
rect3.drawText();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

EDIT:

To rotate your text use the following.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;

let center = {}
var roundRect = function(ctx, x, y, w, h, r) {
  var x2 = x + w;
  var y2 = y + h;
  center = {x: x + w/2, y: y + h/2}
  
  if (w < 2 * r) r = w / 2;
  if (h < 2 * r) r = h / 2;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + r, y);
  ctx.arcTo(x2, y, x2, y2, r);
  ctx.arcTo(x2, y2, x, y2, r);
  ctx.arcTo(x, y2, x, y, r);
  ctx.arcTo(x, y, x2, y, r);
  ctx.closePath();
};



context.fillStyle = 'red';
roundRect(context, 0, 0, 50, 60, 20);
context.fill();

context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.fillText('Hey', center.x, center.y);
context.textAlign = "center";

context.fillStyle = 'red';
roundRect(context, 100, 100, 50, 90, 20);
context.fill();

context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.textBaseline = 'middle';
context.save() //save before you transform something
context.translate(center.x, center.y) //use this to position
context.rotate(degToRad(90)) //rotate here using degrees
context.fillText('Hey', 0, 0) //draw this a (0, 0)
context.fillStyle = 'lightblue'; //delete this
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height) //and this
context.restore() //restore when done with all objects you want affected
context.textAlign = "center";


context.fillStyle = 'red';
roundRect(context, 300, 100, 50, 120, 20);
context.fill();

context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.fillText('Hey', center.x, center.y);
context.textAlign = "center";

function degToRad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks a lot, this works for me, quick question: how can I rotate the text Hey to 90 degrees?

Comment: I added another snippet with an example. If you're not already familiar with transforming on canvas I would recommend looking up how it works. I colored the context blue so you can kind of get an idea of how transforming things work. Essentially rotation always occurs from the top-left corner which Is why we draw the text there and then translate the corner to where we want the text displayed.

Comment: Yeah, I looked in transformation, but I was unable to figure out that the translate was relative and I should pass the co-ordinates there and then set to 0,0 in fill text, as I was passing centre x, y in both of them.

Thanks a lot!